# How to insert input string at a specific location on a .doc document with Python 2.7?

Tags: python-2.7

I want to make a program that will put input string on a specific part of a .doc document
For some reason my cordinates doesent work, i think its a problem with space that add a new row and i dont know how to get around that

i tryed to use non-breaking space '\u00A0'(tbh i dont know the difference)

```
`def SpremanjePodataka():
    sablona = Document()
    Razmak = '\u00A0'
    red = "\n"
    kord = [2, 80, 4, 50, 5, 10]
    red1 = -2
    razmak1 = -1
    global lista
    lista = [U_Naziv_i_sjediste.get(),U_Klasa.get(),U_Urbroj.get(),
             U_Maticni_broj.get(),U_Ime_Prezime.get(),U_Oib.get(),
             U_Ime_Prezime_roditelja.get(),U_Datum_rodenja.get(),
             U_Mjesto_rodenja.get(), U_Drzava_rodenja.get(),
             U_Drzavljanstvo.get(),U_skola_razred_godine_stupanj.get(),
             U_Program_osposobljavanja_Slova.get(),U_Program_osposobljavanja_Broj.get(),
             U_Pohadao_od.get(),U_Pohadao_do.get(),U_nastavne_cjeline.get("1.0","end"),
             U_datum_zavrsne_provjere.get(),U_osposobljen_a.get(),U_U.get(),
             U_nakon_zareza.get(),U_default_datum.get()]
    for text in lista:
        if text:
            red1 = red1 + 2
            razmak1 = razmak1 + 2
            sablona.add_paragraph()`your text`
            redak = sablona.add_paragraph((kord[red1] * red) + (kord[razmak1] * Razmak) + text)
            run = redak.runs[0]
            font = run.font
            font.name = "Minion Pro"
            font.size = Pt(12)
            print(red1)

    sablona.save("Šablona.docx")
    print(lista)`
```